# Эмуляция набора текста

Tags: winapi, клавиатура, текст, эмулятор, ввод

Для эмуляции нажатия клавиш можно использовать **SendInput** (ну или keybd_event). Но при эмуляции ввода строки возникает ряд затруднений:

1. Во время эмуляции (даже не перед, а ВО ВРЕМЯ) юзер может нажимать разные модификаторы: Shift, Ctrl, Alt, Win, который будут влиять на результат работы функции. Да и раскладку нужно учитывать же!
2. Как вводить Unicode-символы? Неужели через `Alt+код`?

Собственно вопрос: как грамотно выполнять эмуляцию ввода строки любых символов независимо от текущего состояния модификаторов и раскладки?

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался! Нужно использовать флаг `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` в поле `dwFlags` структуры `KEYBDINPUT`. Тогда юникод символа нужно будет писать в после `wScan` :)